How do I set up HTTPS across my entire server?
I am running a few different websites on my server.

a general webpage using Apache (port 80)
Cockpit Web Console (port 9090)
Home Assistant (port 8123)
an open-source database system called Teable (port 3000)

I used Certbot to make a certificate for the main website and then copied the certificate files from /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my domain> to places where HA and Cockpit could use them. Sadly I don't know much about the inner workings of Teable so I don't know how to put it behind HTTPS.
I was wondering if there was some sort of solution to set up HTTPS security outside of Teable since I don't know how to put it behind HTTPS from the inside.
My server is running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Apache and Cockpit are packages on the main server, Home Assistant and Teable are Docker containers.


what is a reverse proxy.

You're looking for a reverse proxy - i.e: a server that will accept connections from the general populus, and forward it to a different server based on the request parameters - such as the hostname, path, and other properties.
This reverse proxy service listens on the standard ports (port 80 for HTTP, and 443 for HTTPS), and terminates the secure connection on behalf of the other services behind it. The connection from the reverse proxy to the service behind can be either plain HTTP (ideal for your situation) or HTTPS if you require it. Many of the offerings are also able to automate provisioning and rotating certificates automatically (though you'll generally need the server to be accessible from the internet to provide proof of control), along with automatically discovering the internal services.
I've used the Traefik overview diagram here, because it does a good job of visualising the role of a reverse proxy.

There are a few options that come to mind, and many more that aren't listed here.

Nginx + Certbot - manual configuration required, though there are options like nginx-proxy-manager that simplify and automate this somewhat
Traefik Proxy - can automatically inspect docker services and configure them from labels + manual configuration for other services

